# UK date format query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope this is solvable.

Basically, I'm working with an SQL Server database table and in this table there is a field called `matchdate`. The format of the field is `nchar(50)`.

There are over 2000 records in my table and the dates in the `matchdate` field are all in UK format, for example, "29/04/2014".

I am trying to query the table so I can pull out records between two UK dates. To do this I am using the following query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT * from mytable
WHERE CAST(matchdate as datetime) BETWEEN '" & startdate & "' and '" & enddate & "'
order by cast([matchdate] as datetime) asc"
```

As you can probably tell this type of query is certainly not my strength. If the UK `startdate` value is "01/03/2014" and the UK `enddate` value is "23/04/2014" I get the following error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm guessing this is because I am using two UK dates formats? How do I query the UK formatted "matchdate" field table using UK "start" and UK "end" formatted dates and get around this error?

PS: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the database table.

Comment: The real answer, of course, is to tell whomever looks after the table to stop storing typed data in strings and use the correct column type ([`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.105).aspx)).

Comment: Yep, storing dates *as* dates and using [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681010(v=vs.85).aspx) so that you don't treat them as strings in your asp code would go a long way to fixing this.

Comment: Oh, and of course you shouldn't use `BETWEEN` with [date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Or with any non-integral type, really.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function for the date so that you can specify the date standard
e.g. UK is 103

```
-- test
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '10 January 2014', 103)


SELECT * from mytable WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, matchdate, 103) BETWEEN '" & startdate & "' and '" & enddate & "' order by CONVERT(DATETIME, matchdate, 103) asc"
```

---

Comment: Shouldn't the `ORDER BY` use `CONVERT` as well?